# Any tool to help unit testing?

Tags: phpunit

Im using phpunit. But you know its difficulties, no possibility to mock private functions, to access private variables, etc. Is there a tool which help me? Something to turn private functions to public, turn static method to mockable, etc

Comment: The need to access the private functions and methods of a class is a sign you are doing something wrong (the testing or the tested class or both). Test the interface of the class (i.e. the public methods). You must not care about its internal way of getting the work done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but the best "tool" for making phpunit easier is good design of your code.  If you are not sure what the good design would be for a given problem, you are already using the other good tool available to you - this site.

The things that you mention in your question as causing difficulties are generally difficult because there are issues with the design of your code.  If it is hard to test, it will be hard to refactor, use, and maintain.  The tests show you this early in your coding process and allow you to make changes to save your future self from issues.

For example in the difficulties from your question:

- Mocking private functions - This is a smell that there is a second
  class that needs to be created.  Your object may be violating the
  Single Responsibility Principle.  This function should probably be
  moved into its own object and passed in to system under test.
- Access private variables - PHPUnit does have assertions for object
  attributes ([assertAttributeEquals, etc.](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html)).  However this really
  isn't something that you should need to use.  A private variable is
  an implementation detail of your object, there should be some sort of
  public method that you can use to verify that the proper information
  was set (a getter or dependency injected mock object)
- Mocking static methods - There are many questions on SO about this
  difficulty and many resources saying how static methods are not good
  design.  If you need to mock a static method, that means that you are
  affecting global state.  Static methods are also hiding dependencies
  from users of your object and make things difficult to modify.  Your
  design becomes less flexible and more modular.

Answer (score 2):

Yo **do not** need to test private methods and attributes. They're private for a reason and have sense only when called from inside the class that holds them. More, if you test a public method, you are also indirectly testing the private methods that it calls, and the result of the public function also might depend on some private attributes, which you are also testing with the public method.

If you test all public methods of a class (i.e. its interface), and by this I mean full code/branch coverage on those methods, then you are testing all private methods/attributes that **are needed**. If after testing all public stuff you are left with some pieces of code that wasn't reached, then you can safely delete that code, as it's of no use.